# Como puedo colocar una linea horizontal en medio de un parrafo?

Tags: css, html5

estoy aquí y parecerá tontería pero necesito crear este parrafo en html y no se como poner las lineas horizontales. Lo hice con <hr pero no podia cambiarle el color directamente, intente con un border-color pero no queda en el centro.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que he hecho

```
<div>
  <hr class="hr-smashing">
                            <p>
                                OTHER SMASHING OFFERS
                            </p>
                            <hr class="hr-smashing">
</div>
```

```
.smashing-offers caption p {
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 1.63px;
    color: #1BB286;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 1.5rem;
}
.hr-smashing {
    width: 30%;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #1BB286;
    color: #1BB286;
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Checa [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812770/add-centered-text-to-the-middle-of-a-horizontal-rule). Creo que es justo lo que necesitas. [Esta también](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214127/css-technique-for-a-horizontal-line-with-words-in-the-middle) puede serte útil.

Answer (score 2):

Buen Día.

Según los datos de tú pregunta la respuesta la tienes aquí:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Linea Central con CSS</title>
    <style>
        .hrLinea{
            vertical-align: middle;
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 1px solid #1BB286; 
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <hr class="hrLinea"> OTHER SMASHING OFFERS <hr class="hrLinea">
    </div>
      
</body>
</html>
```

Solo te estaba faltando el centrado vertical:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

El resultado es este:

[image: Con borde de 1px]

IMPORTANTE: Si vas a colocar el ancho del borde de la línea mayor a 3px deberás a comenzar a equilibrar con el margen de la base, por ejemplo:

```
border: 8px solid #1BB286; 
margin-bottom: 12px;
```

El resultado sería este:
[image: Con borde de 8px]

Me tomé el atrevimiento de modificar la forma de presentar los elementos en el HTML y quitar el CSS que sobra.

Answer (score 0):

Una solución puede ser ésta:

```
<div class="box">
<p>OTHER SMASHING OFFERS</p>
</div>
<styles>
.box{
position: relative;
}

.box:after{
content :'';
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height:2px;
background: black;
top:50%;
left: 0;
z-index:-1
}
.box p{
 position: relative;
   background: white;
   width: fit-content;
   margin:0 auto;
   padding: 14px
}
</styles>
```

Espero que te sirva